# facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions is not recognized as a method in the FacebookLogin()?

Tags: flutter, dart, facebook-login

I am stuck with this `fblogin.logInReadWithPermissions` method

I don't seem to understand why the logInReadWithPermissions is giving me this error message `the method 'logInWithReadPermissions' isn't defined for the class 'FacebookLogin'`

This is a class I made to call when a button is pressed to check the facebook login results:

```
  void initiateFacebookLogin() async {
    fbLogin = new FacebookLogin();
    var facebookLoginResult =
    await fbLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email']);
    switch (facebookLoginResult.status) {
      case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
        print("YOU GOT A ERROR");
        onLoginStatusChanged(false);
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        print("CancelledByUser");
        onLoginStatusChanged(false);
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        print("LoggedIn");
        onLoginStatusChanged(true);
        break;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem when I updated to version 3.0.0. It seems that in that version the logInWithReadPermissions function disappears and you have to use logIn instead.

```
final facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
final result = await facebookLogin.logIn(['email']);
```

Comment: They should also change their documentation.

Answer (score 5):

`logInWithReadPermissions` is deprecated method 
Just replace `logInWithReadPermissions(['email']);` with `logIn(['email']);`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  final FacebookLogin _facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
  final FacebookLoginResult result =
      await _facebookLogin.logIn(['email']);
```

and make sure you have added latest flutter_facebook_login package

```
dependencies:
    flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
```